# Add a new column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add a new column (named `'sick'`) filled with `"yes"` in a `DataFrame` (`df`).

I tried the following code but this is not working:

```
df['sick']=print(df['sick']=="yes")
```

Do you have any suggestions please?

Comment: df['sick'] = 'yes'

Comment: the `print` function is only to print a result to the console. You would never use it for an assignment. You can just assign the value to the column directly as the other answers have indicated.